# How to find top features for each classes in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to find the 3 top features for each of the 3 classes in my dataframe using the `.corr()` function in a dataframe. I tried doing that using the below code but I am getting a NaN value for my features.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create sample data with 9 features and a target column of 3 classes
np.random.seed(123)
data = np.random.randn(1000, 9)
target = np.random.choice([1, 2, 3], size=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['feature_1', 'feature_2', 'feature_3', 'feature_4', 'feature_5', 'feature_6', 'feature_7', 'feature_8', 'feature_9'])
df['target'] = target

# Find correlation for 3 top features for each of the 3 classes
classes = [1,2,3]
top_features = 3

for cls in classes:
    print(f"Top {top_features} features for class {cls}:")
    class_df = df[df['target'] == cls]
    corr = class_df.corr()['target'].abs().sort_values(ascending=False)
    print(corr)
    #top_corr_features = corr[1:top_features+1].index.tolist()
    #print(class_df[top_corr_features].corr())
enter code here
```

**what I simply want is the top features for each of 3 classes: 3*3 = 9 features**

output.

```
Top 3 features for class 1:
feature_1   NaN
feature_2   NaN
feature_3   NaN
feature_4   NaN
feature_5   NaN
feature_6   NaN
feature_7   NaN
feature_8   NaN
feature_9   NaN
target      NaN
Name: target, dtype: float64
Top 3 features for class 2:
feature_1   NaN
feature_2   NaN
feature_3   NaN
feature_4   NaN
feature_5   NaN
feature_6   NaN
feature_7   NaN
feature_8   NaN
feature_9   NaN
target      NaN
Name: target, dtype: float64
Top 3 features for class 3:
feature_1   NaN
feature_2   NaN
feature_3   NaN
feature_4   NaN
feature_5   NaN
feature_6   NaN
feature_7   NaN
feature_8   NaN
feature_9   NaN
target      NaN
Name: target, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Please explain what you really want to do, it's currently unclear. You can't compute a correlation with a unique feature (using the feature value itself).

Comment: @mozway for each unique target(1,2,3), I want to find the top 3 features that correlate with each target. e.g target 1, top 3 features, target 2, top 3 features,

Comment: @mozway what I simply want is the top features for each of 3 classes: 3*3 = 9 features

Comment: It does not make sense to speak of a correlation of any feature with a unique target value. If the target value is fixed, there is no correlation to calculate, hence the NaN values you get.

Comment: @Arne by having a fixed target value, do you mean having a single value for all targets? e.g 1

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.